# Change colour of JTextField using ActionListner

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I just basically want the colour to change back to white when i click the button again;

This is the code i have to get it to change on the first click;

```
private void colourButton()
{
    inputField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

// listener method 
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e)
{
    inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
    resultMessage.setText("Colour Button Pressed");
}
```

Now i just want to be able to click it again the colour of the inputField should go back to White.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(inputField.getBackground() == Color.RED)
{
inputField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
} 
else
{
inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far you have code to change the colour of the text field when you click a button, so it seems that all you need now is to add a conditional statement in to decide what colour to change it to based on what it already is.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e)
{
    if (inputField.getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
        inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
    } else {
        inputField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    resultMessage.setText("Colour Button Pressed");
}
```

You might also want to look into performing the actual colour change in the GUI thread using something like [`invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091835/java-swingutilities-invokelater) has some more info on this.